# Why does TypeScript show me error, when I change DOM-element via getElementsByClassName(), but application works anyway?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

I have angular2 application. Due to some problems I forced to use inside method of component such code (I understand that it's over than bad, but ...):|

```
let confirmWindowDOM = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0];
confirmWindowDOM.style['z-index'] = "2049";
```

It produces the error, which I can see in console:

```
(program):75 ./some/path/to/component.component.ts
(103,28): error TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.
```

But anyway application works as I expected.

So there are some questions:

1. This code is clear JS. As I understand TypeScript as superset of JavaScript must has no problem with that, however I have error and tests are failed. Even if I change code like this: document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].style['z-index'] = "1051";;
2. How I can suppress this error or fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns collection of `Element`. You can use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) in order to inform typescript that it is actually `HTMLElement`:

```
let confirmWindowDOM = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0] as HTMLElement;
```